# Table sorter not working with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tablesorter

I am using table sorter plugin. However I am not able to build the table when using JSON. Do you know where the problem is? This is the plugin:

> http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-build-table.html#setup__object_json_file_via_ajax

And my attempt:

> http://jsbin.com/novixuqo/7/edit

```
var opts = {
  "theme": "blue",
  "widgetOptions": {
    "build_type": "json",
    "build_source": {
      "url": "http://jsbin.com/qinikepu/4/js",
      "dataType": "json"
    }
  }
};

console.log(opts);

$('#object2Table2').tablesorter(opts);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're making a cross domain request for the JSON, so the AJAX request cannot be completed.

Meaning if you wanted this to work you would have to have the JSON data on the same domain as the request came from.

Here's a quick way to mock an AJAX request by including the data inside of the Javascript, and then making a POST request to JSFiddle's echo service, which replies back with the data that you POSTed.

This is done by changing the `build_source` option like so:

```
 build_source : { url: '/echo/json/', 
                 data: data,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 type: "POST",
                 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YV9AH/)

Edit:
I forgot to include that you are missing the `http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-build-table.js` script. I only had the cross domain issue, since I was using JSFiddle (D'oh) but it works fine on JSBin with this link thanks to Mottie. 
http://jsbin.com/novixuqo/11/edit?js,output

Comment: Actually, the problem was that he linked to the [wrong build file](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/557#issuecomment-39059897). It's not a cross-domain issue in this case, but I'll still give you a +1. Updated demo: http://jsbin.com/novixuqo/11/edit?js,output

Comment: Ah ya. That's the first thing that I saw, but I ended up moving it over to JSFiddle and forgot that the JSON was actually on the JSBin domain itself. Edited my answer with the actual problem included. Thanks for the +1!